# Get non empty values of dataframe as a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have a **sparse** dataframe and would like to get all non empty values as a single column. See the image that I made up to illustrate the problem. I somehow managed to solve it using the python code below. However, I feel there migh be some **better | simpler | efficient** way to solve it
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ["x1","x2","?","?","?","?"]
list2 = ["?","?","y1","y2","?","?"]
list3 = ["?","?","?","?","z1","z2"]

df_sparse = pd.DataFrame({"A":list1,"B":list2,"C":list3})
values_vect = []
for col in df_sparse.columns:
  values = [ i for i in list(df_sparse[col]) if i !="?"]
  values_vect.extend(values)
df_sparse["D"] = pd.DataFrame(values_vect,columns=["D"])
display(df_sparse)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df_sparse["D"] = df_sparse.replace("?", np.nan).ffill(axis="columns").iloc[:, -1]
```

- replace "?"s with NaNs
- forward fill the values along columns so that non-NaN values will slide to the rightmost positions
- query the rightmost column, that's where the values are

to get

```py
>>> df_sparse

    A   B   C   D
0  x1   ?   ?  x1
1  x2   ?   ?  x2
2   ?  y1   ?  y1
3   ?  y2   ?  y2
4   ?   ?  z1  z1
5   ?   ?  z2  z2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using masking, `stack` and `groupby.last`:

```
df_sparse['D'] = (df_sparse
 .where(df_sparse.ne('?'))
 .stack()
 .groupby(level=0).last()
 )

print(df_sparse)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  x1   ?   ?  x1
1  x2   ?   ?  x2
2   ?  y1   ?  y1
3   ?  y2   ?  y2
4   ?   ?  z1  z1
5   ?   ?  z2  z2
```